# JestJS.io: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_FILE_URL_PATH]: File URL path must be absolute

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I have a fresh installation of NodeJS on Windows 10 and try to install JEST (jestjs.io), installed through repeated calls of

```
npm install --save-dev jest
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jest ts-jest
```

because it complained about the babel and other types. I repeated both commands and then it did not bring up errors, saying that more packages were installed.
When I run the sum test

```
mh@CL MINGW64 /h/RR_NodeJS/JEST
$ npm run test

> @ test H:\RR_NodeJS
> jest

 FAIL  JEST/sum.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_FILE_URL_PATH]: File URL path must be absolute



Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.754 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-13T16_02_40_985Z-debug.log
```

I already resolved the paths as Visual Studio Code proposed to absolute ones:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
export default sum;
```

(last line) and

```
import sum from '/h/RR_NodeJS/JEST/sum';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

But still, get the same error message and the test is not successful. I already tried another setup where I installed through yarn instead of npm and that ended up in the same error. I found similar reports about the error message here on stackoverflow and other pages but none of them helped me to get it running. What should I do to get it running?

Comment: Can please someone give an advice on this?

Comment: I have the same problem. But it is not jest, it is yargs https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1754

Comment: Would be interesting to have some insight on this one. Based on other similar questions that have gone unanswered, could it truly be said that it appears Stack Overflow doesn't care about `ERR_INVALID_FILE_URL_PATH]: File URL path must be absolute` questions?